# Why does LINQ generated SQL include multiple "IS NULL" conditions for the same column

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

The following query against a SQL Server 2012 database, using Entity Framework Core 3.1:

```
        var tows = await _context.DataEntryTow
            .Where(t => _context.DataEntrySample
                        .Any(s => s.TowId==t.TowId && (s.MicroscopeId != "0" || s.MicroscopeId == null)))
            .Select (t => new { text = t.TowId, value = t.TowId });
```

generates this SQL:

```
SELECT d.tow_id AS text
FROM data_entry_tow AS d
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM data_entry_sample AS d0
    WHERE (d0.tow_id = d.tow_id) AND (((d0.microscope_id <> '0') OR (d0.microscope_id IS NULL)) OR (d0.microscope_id IS NULL)))
```

I don't *think* I've done anything wrong, and I'm fairly sure the query optimizer will eliminate the second `(d0.microscope_id IS NULL)`, but it still seems like an error in the LINQ code.

**MicroscopeId** is defined:

```
    public string MicroscopeId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Field `MicroscopeId` declared as nullable. So, to mimic LINQ to Objects behaviour when `null != "0"` is `true` but in SQL `null <> '0'` is false, EF Core generates additional `OR` condition.

To disable this geneeration you have to specify that when building DbContextOptions:

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(constr, b => b.UseRelationalNulls(true) );
```

Additional info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/null-comparisons#using-relational-null-semantics

Comment: Excellent.  I'm pretty sure that any significant SQL database is going to optimize that out, anyway, so I'm not concerned, but it _was_ driving me nuts!